# Will the lts kernel update their driver to support newer hardware in the future?

Tags: kernel, 16.04

The developers choose linux 4.4LTS as the kernel of Ubuntu 16.04LTS, will the kernel update its driver for newer hardware in the future? Or will they just upgrade the kernel version for Ubuntu 16.04.1 or 16.04.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel will get security and bug fixing updates.

Also some of new hardware support, that does not require appending lots of code, will be backported from the later kernels to Ubuntu 4.4 kernel.

Ubuntu 16.04.2 will probably have a brand new major kernel version.

Comment: You mean 16.04.1 won't stick on kernel 4.4?

Comment: It is to be decided. Probably 16.04.1 will still have 4.4. But 16.04.2 should have a newer kernel borrowed from the next non-LTS release.